# WordPress One Site, Multiple Domains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cookies, multiple-domains

I have two domains, primarydomain.com and secondarydomain.com. They both point to the same Wordpress site.

When someone visits the site using secondarydomain.com, I append a url parameter using htaccess rewrite rules. If that parameter is detected, I serve up a slightly different layout.

My problem is that if a user logs in on primarydomain.com, then goes to secondarydomain.com, they are no longer logged into the site. I believe this has to do with the authentication cookie being set specifically on primarydomain.com.

Is there a way to set the cookie for both domains?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible when the domains are **primarydomain.com** and **secondarydomain.com** due to security issues.

The only option i see is to use subdomains

**p.domain.com** and **s.domain.com** can easily be configured to share cookies

for wordpress just add the followin to your wp-config:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'domain.com');
```

I suppose you could trigger some sort of cookies sync if you could pass a cookie_id to the secondarydomain and then lookup cookies via database. (probably would lead to more issues).